# How to convert 2D points back after applying homography to an entire image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, homography, perspectivecamera

I am new to opencv and image related geometry. But now I am working some image processing tasks.
Here is what I did:
Given pts_src, pts_dst, I warped the entire image with cv2.findHomograpy() and cv2.warpPerspective()

cv2.findHomography provided me with a 3x3 homography matrix.
cv2.warpPerspective() provided me with a warpped image, and I can detect some feature points from this warpped image.

However, I need to map the feature point coordinates back to the original input image.
Could someone please tell me how to achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I think that the inverse of the homography matrix wil be the new matrix to map from dst_points back to src_points

Comment: @alan.elkin Thanks for the response. I tried numpy.linalg.inv(H)*np.transpose(np.matrix[[x, y, 1]]), and obtained a 3-d vector V. Then I tried V[0], V[1] and it seems it is not the correct location. Did I do something wrong here?

Comment: @alan.elkin  Is the 3rd element of V the scaling factor here?  I plotted (V[0]/V[2], V[1]/V[2]) can the point seems to be at the desired position. I am not sure if it is always the case.

Comment: Does [this help?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61147385/13253198)

Comment: @gnodab Your link points to this same OP

Comment: @alan.elkin I’m sorry. I don’t know what happened

Comment: there is a function to transform points https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void%20perspectiveTransform(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20InputArray%20m) to invert the transformation direction, just invert the 3x3 transformation matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the inverse of the homography matrix wil be the new matrix to map from `pts_dst` back to `pts_src`.

As you said in a comment and as shown [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gad327659ac03e5fd6894b90025e6900a7), it seems that your 3rd component is, indeed, a scaling coefficient `w` of the resulting vector:

> `(x, y) → (x′/w, y′/w)`
>   where `(x′, y′, w′) = mat ⋅ [x y 1]`
>   (...) In case of a 2D vector transformation, the z component is omitted.

So you could rescale it by doing `(V[0]/V[2], V[1]/V[2])`, just like you mentioned in your comment.

Also, I think this scaling factor has something to do with how the matrix is generated, so please check the details of the matrix as well, as the official [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga4abc2ece9fab9398f2e560d53c8c9780) of `cv2.findHomography()` says:

> Homography matrix is determined up to a scale. Thus, it is normalized so that h33=1.

Hope this helps!